# Help identifying a few small bar and clip pieces

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

There are a handful of parts I cannot identify and I would be super happy if anyone could help!

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

Comment: thank you SO MUCH @jncraton !!!

Comment: No problem. I'm happy I could help.

Answer (score 10):

[Bar 1L with Top Stud and Two Side Studs](https://rebrickable.com/parts/92690/bar-1l-with-top-stud-and-two-side-studs/)

[image: part photo]

[Arm Skeleton [Bent / 2 Clips]](https://rebrickable.com/parts/93609/arm-skeleton-bent-2-clips/)

[image: part photo]

[Bar 4L](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30374/bar-4l-lightsaber-blade-wand/)

[image: part photo]

[3.2 Shaft w/3.2 Hole](https://rebrickable.com/parts/23443/32-shaft-w32-hole/0/)

[image: part photo]

[Flag 2 x 2 Trapezoid](https://rebrickable.com/parts/44676/flag-2-x-2-trapezoid/)

[image: part photo]